# How to GRANT SELECT by default to B, on tables created by A?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

**Background**
In my PostgreSQL instance (say with one unique database constituted of one table only), I have 2 users:

- `user_A`, who can create and populate `my_table`,
- `user_B`, who should only be able to read (`SELECT`) from it.

It happens that, because of an API I do not control, `user_A` keeps dropping and recreating `my_table` from scratch.
This causes a reset of `user_B` privileges on `my_table`.

Thus, I am forced to

```
my_db=# GRANT SELECT on TABLE my_table TO user_B;
```

every time `user_A` recreates `my_table`.

*Notes:*
I know (cf. [Grant permissions to user for any new tables created in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309416/5433628)) default privileges can only be set for objects created by the user they are granted to (i.e., that would be easier to set default privileges to `user_B` for tables created by `user_B`) — but this is not the case here.

Moreover, as mentioned in question linked above, [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) specifies that *"You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of"*.
So I could have

```
CREATE ROLE super_role;
GRANT super_role TO user_A;
GRANT super_role TO user_B;
```

and then `SET ROLE super_role` before `user_A` creates the table… but I unfortunately have no control over how `user_A` creates it.

**Question**
How can I `GRANT SELECT` by default to `user_B` on tables created by `user_A`?

Comment: maybe a view over the table and grant user_b access to that?

Comment: @JonathanFite I'll look into that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL has *default privileges*, the perfect tool for your requirement:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user_a
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user_b;
```

Now `user_b` will automatically get `SELECT` privileges on all tables created by `user_a`.

Comment: If I have to allow default access to tables belonging to multiple users then is there any way to do it without generating multiple scripts?

Comment: @asds_asds No!!